# Input won't trim

Tags: java, swing, input, joptionpane

Brand new to this but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong as the output will not trim.

```
package cs520.hw3.part1;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter data using the format Name, Age, City");
        //String delimiter = ",";
        //String[] tokens = input.split(delimiter);
        System.out.println(input.trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you expect from the trim function?

Comment: What's the output you get and what did you expect?

Comment: Please take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Comment: I was expecting it to print whenever was entered in the input box minus any spaces but it just leaves the spaces in the print.

Comment: `trim()` removes spaces from the start and end of the string. It doesn't remove spaces from the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between removing the leading & trailing spaces (using `trim()` and replacing **all** spaces from a `String` (using [`replaceAll(" ", "")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-))

### Example output

```
' Andrew,      52,  Sydney         '
'Andrew,      52,  Sydney'
'Andrew,52,Sydney'
```

1. Raw String
2. `trim()`
3. `replaceAll(" ", "")`

### Code

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TrimSpace {
    
    TrimSpace() {
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                "Name, Age, City", 
                "Person Details", 
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        // show the raw string entered by user
        System.out.println(String.format("'%1s'", s));
        // remove leading & trailing space from string
        System.out.println(String.format("'%1s'", s.trim()));
        // remove all spaces from string
        System.out.println(String.format("'%1s'", s.replaceAll(" ", "")));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TrimSpace();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, it would be better (user experience) to offer the user 3 fields for this. Two text fields (for name & city) and one spinner (for age).

Answer (score 0):

The `trim()` method returns a copy of your string with leading and trailing white space removed, or the same string if it has no leading or trailing white space.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String Str = new String("   Some string with whitespace in front and after it.   ");

      System.out.print("Return Value :" );
      System.out.println(Str.trim() );
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Return Value :Some string with whitespace in front and after it.
```

Comment: I understand that and it works when just a static string value but I want it to trim off any spaces from data that was entered in the input box.

Comment: Provide an example of your problem please